# LoginButton with native Fragment

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to implement the Facebook LoginButton using the tutorial here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0#step2

The problem is on the line `authButton.setFragment(this);`.

I'm using native fragments (android.app.Fragment) but setFragment expects a support Fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment).

EDIT: I cannot switch to support Fragments, I have a big app that uses native Fragments.

Comment: see the updated answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is the wrapper class below. Using this you can just call

```
authButton.setFragment(new NativeFragmentWrapper(this));
```

The wrapper is a support fragment and just passes the method calls from the facebook LoginButton to the native fragment. I'm using this and it works fine.

```
public class NativeFragmentWrapper extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private final Fragment nativeFragment;

    public NativeFragmentWrapper(Fragment nativeFragment) {
        this.nativeFragment = nativeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        nativeFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        nativeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting ``` java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null``` in inside AppEventsLogger constructor

Comment: This is an old answer. The Facebook sdk has probably changed since. Apparently they try to read the context from the fragment. Maybe, you have to actually attach the wrapper fragment to an Activity to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by using the activity context instead of the fragment context and passing the "onActivityResult" from the Activity, to the fragment to the callbackManager.

Just follow the following instructions:

1. *Don't* call **loginButton.setFragment(fragment)**. Per default, the Activity context of the LoginButton is used.
2. Add the following method *inside the activity* of your fragment, to catch and pass any result to the fragment:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       final MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
       if (fragment != null) {
           fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Override **onActivityResult** also *inside your fragment* which contains the LoginButton and pass the result to the callbackManager.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```

I hope it works.

Comment: This worked for me after switching from v4.Fragment to app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

The reason is obvious. Facebook SDK is using the Fragment class from the support library for making it backward compatible and work with older versions of android (API Level < 11). And you **must** use the same class in your application as well.

Include the support library `android-support-v4.jar` in to the `libs` folder and use the Fragment class from it (for Ant based projects). If you are using Gradle build system, Follow the instruction given in Lei's answer above.

**Update:** If your application have high dependency with native library, then you are left with a single option. The Facebook SDK code is available [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). Fork it and change the SDK to use native library (Remove the support library from the SDK itself). But keep in mind that, your application will be limited to run on API level greater than 10 (minSdkVersion should be 11).

Comment: Forking is a bad idea. I'm sure the Facebook SDK can be made to work with native fragments, if nothing else I can make the call from the Activity, or I don't have to use LoginButton. I'm just trying to find out the recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Remove import android.app.Fragment;
2. Add import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
3. Right click on your Project and Select properties.
4. Build Path > Library > Add External Library > Locate your android-support-v4.jar                        file(sdk > extras > android > supports > v4)

Answer (score -2):

Add this below in you **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Then import **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**  instead of the native fragment.