# Android Facebook SDK for API level > 11

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

Is there a way of using the Facebook SDK with API level that is greater than 11?
ATM when I'm trying to use the regular fragments and not the support fragments I'm getting errors like the following :

> Error:(178, 19) error: method setFragment in class LoginButton cannot be applied to given     types;
>   required: Fragment
>   found: FragmentEntrance
>   reason: actual argument FragmentEntrance cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion

I've tried changing the FB SDK fragments to the regular ones but I'm getting many errors.
Is there a clean way of doing so without messing with their SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've came up with a solution that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380391/878244) on StackOverflow after many searches, well apparently Facebook wants to support as many devices as it can (Duh...) but a user here came up with a workaround that lets you use the regular android.app.Fragment -

```
public class NativeFragmentWrapper extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private final Fragment nativeFragment;

public NativeFragmentWrapper(Fragment nativeFragment) {
    this.nativeFragment = nativeFragment;
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    nativeFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    nativeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   } 
}
```

An a case of usage can be the following:

```
 LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
 authButton.setFragment(new NativeFragmentWrapper(this));
```