# Android Facebook setFragment with a regular Fragment

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

Because setFragment of Facebook is working only with support.fragment, I did the following in order to overcome this when working with regular fragment:

```
public class NativeFragmentWrapper extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private final Fragment nativeFragment;

    public NativeFragmentWrapper(Fragment nativeFragment) {
        this.nativeFragment = nativeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        nativeFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        nativeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

and in the login page where facebook button resides, I did the following:

```
authButton.setFragment(new new NativeFragmentWrapper(this));
```

in Eclipse it worked great but Android Studio 1.0.2 is complaining:

This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments). From the Fragment documentation: Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().

So I tried this:

```
NativeFragmentWrapper f = new NativeFragmentWrapper();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
f.setArguments(bundle);
authButton.setFragment(f);
```

but I didn't find a way to put "this" (which is a Fragment) inside the bundle in order to retrieve it in the wrapper constructor.

I can @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Maybe you thought it worked great in eclipse, but you didnt see the crash when the activity was destroyed and recreated due to memory. I would just change the facebook code to use native fragments. Its a minor change actually

Comment: But Facebook will update their sdk, I will need to re-do it until they change something completely and i'll get stuck. I never saw a problem in my tests, it could be that I never got to the problematic scenario but if that's a real extreme case, I'll handle it when/if relevant.

Comment: Honestly what you are trying to do doesnt even seem like it could possibly work. You are extending fragment but dont ever call into the native fragment - onCreate, onCreateView, etc. Not there. Did you remove some code?

Comment: Nope, I took it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644599/loginbutton-with-native-fragment - maybe it won't work on a specific scenario that I didn't encounter yet but for now, all I want is to finish migrating my project to Android Studio because in eclipse I had no warnings/errors about it.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering how to fix this small thing :)

Comment: How can I put a fragment inside a bundle to another fragment? that will solve me problem

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just use the Fragment class from the v4 support libraries in your app, the signatures are the same, and you just need to change the import statements.

Failing that, the solution in the other post can potentially work (haven't tried it myself), and to solve your problem, just have 2 constructors (one the default, and another that takes a Fragment parameter), and just use the right constructor (i.e. not the default) when you create the wrapper object.

Comment: I started with that but then had a different problem that made me switch to regular Fragment. Even when I add a new constructor with no params, I still get the error. Bottom line: How can I put a fragment inside a bundle to another fragment? that will solve me problem